# Easier way of getting google-drive auth code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run a Rails app using the [google-drive-ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem, and getting the authorization code is currently slightly unwieldy- after redirecting from google the auth code is returned in the URL of the page like so:

`localhost:3000/g_auths/redir?code=4/[code]`

So at the moment I'm getting at the code with this slightly unwieldy snip:

```
authorization_code = request.original_url.to_s
authorization_code = authorization_code[g_auths_redir_url.to_s.length + 6..-1] + '#'
```

Now, while this does give the correct code, I wonder if there is an easier and more dynamic way of doing this?

Comment: I suggest you to use an official gem from google here [google-api-ruby](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client) and this for gdrive documentation in ruby https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/ruby

Comment: @rails_id thanks for your response. No offense, but that's not something I can switch to at the moment- the rest of the code works and it's not worth refactoring half of a project purely to improve 2 lines.